# Python OOP: how to use a flag parameter to access methods?

Tags: python, oop, flags

It's unclear to me how one accomplishes this in Python, though I am confused about the fundamentals of OOP:

Let's say I create a `Shape` class, and use this as an example.

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def area(self):
        return self.x * self.y

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y

    def scaleSize(self,scale):
        self.x = self.x * scale
        self.y = self.y * scale
```

In my case, I must create a Class which inputs a file whereby there are only two types, `file_typeA` and `file_typeB`. For the user, it would be exceptionally cumbersome to use a Class for `Type A` and a Class for `Type B`.

```
## use case for an a "read in file name" class `filename`
foo = filename(path = "path/to/file.txt", file_type = "TypeA")
```

My question is, how do I restrict the "Type A" methods for a file initialized with flag `file_type="TypeA"`, and restrict the methods for a file initialized with flag `file_type = "TypeB"`?

Let's try the `Shape` class again, whereby the two types are `Square` and `Triangle`. The *wrong* way to code this is something like this:

```
class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x, y, type):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.type = type

    if type == "Square":

        def area(self):
            return self.x * self.y

        def perimeter(self):
            return 2 * self.x + 2 * self.y

        def scaleSize(self,scale):
            self.x = self.x * scale
            self.y = self.y * scale

    elif type == "Triangle":

        def hooray(self):
            print("HOORAY! It's hip to be a triangle!")

    else:
        print("'type' must be either Circle or Triangle")

 ## example Class instantiation
 bar = Shape(2, 3, type="Square")
```

For such a class, how do I create it such that the method `area` cannot be used for a `Shape` of type=="TypeB"?

Comment: why not inheriting your shape class instead? yes, you must read more abour OOP. You could also use a factory method to instanciate the proper class.

Comment: _In my case, I must create a Class which inputs a file whereby there are only two types, file`_typeA` and file `_typeB`_. What are you trying to say here? Especially explain what you mean by **inputs**

Comment: For your shape example, you'd do a `class Square` and a `class Triangle`, and if you want a square you *don't* do `Shape(type='square')` but `Square()`.

Comment: @smac89 It could be `type=txt` or `type=pdf`

Comment: @deceze I realize that. However, the function I am building takes in a file of two types. The user must specify these types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to define a mother class:

```
class Shape:
   pass
```

then sub-classes

```
class Triangle(Shape):
   # whatever methods there are
```

What you're describing is a *factory* function which creates the proper object according to some parameter:

```
def create(type):
   if type=="Triangle":
       return Triangle()
   elif type=="Square":
       return Square()
```

but it's not very useful since the caller has to pass the name of the class instead:

```
c = create("Triangle")
```

instead of just doing:

```
c = Triangle()
```

Well, it may have its interest when saving/restoring a program state from a text file containing the type(s) of the objects in the program memory when saved (if you don't want to use `pickle`).

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you OOP! OOP helps to *eliminate* those kinds of conditionals. You should create a `Shape` base class, then use that to define subclasses for each individual kind of shape. The subclasses should include the methods needed for that kind of shape.

If you want the caller to be able to specify a shape using a string, for example because they are using data from a file or the user, you can write a factory method to do that. You can actually ask Python for the subclasses of your class; no need to list them out! [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

```
class Shape(object):
     __subs = {}

     @classmethod
     def of_type(cls, name, *args, **kwargs):
         """Factory method that instantiates Shape subclasses given their name as a string"""
         lname = name.lower()
         subs = cls._Shape__subs
         if cls is Shape:
             if not subs:        # build subclass dictionary
                 subs.update({c.__name__.lower(): c for c in cls.__subclasses__()})
             if lname in subs:   # instantiate the named subclass
                 return subs[lname](*args, **kwargs)
             raise NameError("invalid shape name: %s" % name)
         raise TypeError("of_type() may be called only on Shape base class")

class Square(Shape):
     pass

class Triangle(Shape):
     pass

# set tri to an instance of type Triangle
tri = Shape.of_type("Triangle")
```

Note that the factory method passes through any arguments given after the name. Class names are case-insensitive.

Comment: What does `of_type` do?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that `Shape.of_type("Triangle")` returns an instance of `Triangle`?